# What is the difference between capacity and node_counts in the sklearn.tree.tree.Tree?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I would like to export the decision tree structure from python. Hence I consider saving every node of the tree. In the doc of Tree from sklearn, I find two attribute capacity and node_counts very similar. In my current usage, they are always the same. But I am wondering what's their main difference?

https://www.kite.com/python/docs/sklearn.tree.tree.Tree

Answer (score 0):

From the document that you referenced:

- node_count - The **current** number of nodes.
- capacity - The maximum number of nodes that this tree can hold before it becomes necessary to re-size internal buffers.

node_count is always <= capacity.

At the same time, the tree does not want to increase capacity beyond node_count too much, because unused internal buffers can consume quite lot of memory.

TLDR: When writing a tree exporter, then you should pay attention to node_count, not capacity.

Comment: But for a decision tree that is already trained, should node_count always be equal to capacity?

Comment: Not necessarily - re-sizing buffers so that node_count == capacity would be an extra computation. Maybe the unused capacity is not that big after training to warrant spending extra time/memory (at least temporarily), without any visible benefit to the end user.